# Bit complexity of computing the sign of an expression evaluated at an algebraic number

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, polynomials

I have a univariate polynomial $F(t)\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ of degree $d$ and maximum bitsize of coefficients equal to $\tau$ and $G(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ of degree $d^2$ and maximum bitsize of coefficients equal to $d^2+d\tau$.

Consider also $P(t), Q(t)\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ of degree $d^2$ and maximum bitsize of coefficients equal to $d^2+d\tau$.

For a root $\xi$ of $G(t)$, I want to check if $F(\frac{P(\xi)}{Q(\xi)})$ is equal to zero or not. 
What is the most efficient way of doing this in terms of bit complexity?